# MongoDB Aggregate Query to find the documents with missing values

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am having a huge collection of objects where the data is stored for different employees.

```json
{
  "employee": "Joe",
  "areAllAttributesMatched": false,
  "characteristics": [
    {
      "step": "A",
      "name": "house",
      "score": "1"
    },
    {
      "step": "B",
      "name": "car"
    },
    {
      "step": "C",
      "name": "job",
      "score": "3"
    }
  ]
}
```

There are cases where the score for an object is completely missing and I want to find out all these details from the database.
In order to do this, I have written the following query, but seems I am going wrong somewhere due to which it is not displaying the output.

[image]

I want the data in the following format for this query, so that it is easy to find out which employee is missing the score for which step and which name.

[image]

Comment: Consider replacing your image of code by actual text so others are easier to copy and paste to study and reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$characteristics"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "characteristics.score": {
        "$exists": false
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "employee": 1,
      "name": "$characteristics.name",
      "step": "$characteristics.step",
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

You need to use `$exists` to check the existence

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3DPIh_WU2Xu)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$ifNull` to handle both cases of 1. the `score` field is missing 2. `score` is null.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$characteristics"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [
          {
            "$ifNull": [
              "$characteristics.score",
              null
            ]
          },
          null
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      _id: null,
      documents: {
        $push: {
          "employee": "$employee",
          "name": "$characteristics.name",
          "step": "$characteristics.step",
          
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: false
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WazYovLxFiy) for your reference.